# Android location service broadcast

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I know there are many answers to this question, but I can't find a working one.

I have a working Location service, in locationResult after getting location put this code:

`Intent intent = new Intent("CURRENT_LOCATION"); intent.putExtra("lat", latitude); intent.putExtra("lon", longitude); sendBroadcast(intent);`

But can't receive in MainActivity.
Can anyone help me with code in MainActivity and in Manifest if needed.
Thanks

Comment: Can you share the code of how you have send and received the broadcast

Comment: Thanks, is funny but after days looking for how to register receiver with action intent, after wrote this question I have found today a YouTube clear tutorial.